# Identify first row amongst similar set of data from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to the one shown below:

```
    BillNumber Description            LineAmount   TotalAmount
0   INV001     Line Item 1 of INV001  500          700
1   INV001     Line Item 2 of INV001  200          700
2   INV002     Line Item 1 of INV002  100          800
3   INV002     Line Item 2 of INV002  300          800
4   INV002     Line Item 3 of INV002  400          800
```

What I want is as follows:

```
    BillNumber Description            LineAmount   TotalAmount  NewBill
0   INV001     Line Item 1 of INV001  500          700          Yes
1   INV001     Line Item 2 of INV001  200          700
2   INV002     Line Item 1 of INV002  100          800          Yes
3   INV002     Line Item 2 of INV002  300          800
4   INV002     Line Item 3 of INV002  400          800
```

I want to identify the first row of every new BillNumber and mark the value 'Yes' for it under new column named 'NewBill'. How can we achieve this using pandas ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df['NewBill'] = np.where(df['BillNumber'].duplicated(), '', 'Yes')
print (df)
  BillNumber            Description  LineAmount  TotalAmount NewBill
0     INV001  Line Item 1 of INV001         500          700     Yes
1     INV001  Line Item 2 of INV001         200          700        
2     INV002  Line Item 1 of INV002         100          800     Yes
3     INV002  Line Item 2 of INV002         300          800        
4     INV002  Line Item 3 of INV002         400          800
```

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
df.loc[df['BillNumber'].duplicated(), 'NewBill'] = 'Yes'
```